# MySQL in Slick 3.1

Tags: scala, slick

I've been going through the Slick examples and trying to use them to connect to a MySQL database. However the sbt console complains that it cannot find the value column:

```
class MySQLCatalogue(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Long, String, String)](tag, "COLUMNS") {
  def pos: Column[Long] = column[Long]("ORDINAL_POSITION")
  def id: Column[String] = column[String]("COLUMN_NAME")
  def dtype: Column[String] = column[String]("DATA_TYPE")

  def * = (pos, id, dtype)
}
```

The examples I find online import `scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._` but that import doesn't do it. Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: can you provide the compiler output?

Comment: and the imports you are using

Answer (score 2):

Try these imports:

```
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider // if you are using play-slick
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using play 2.5.x with Guice dependency Injection.

You have to import `dbConfig.driver.api._`

```
@Singleton 
class UsersRepo @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider:DatabaseConfigProvider) {
 val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
 import dbConfig.driver.api._
 val users = TableQuery[Users]

 class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, UsersTable.name) {
   def id = column[UserId]("user_id", O.PrimaryKey)
   def email = column[Email]("email")
   def * = (email, id) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
   def emailIndex = index("users_email_index", email, true)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
case class Keyword(keyword: String, active: Int, id: Long = 0L)
class KeywordTable(tag : Tag) extends Table[Keyword](tag, "COLUMNS") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def keyword = column[String]("keyword")
  def active = column[Int]("active")
  def * = (keyword,active,id) <> (Keyword.tupled, Keyword.unapply)
}
```

This example works (Playframework 2.5.4 and Slick 3.1)